# How to call controller in side the view LARAVEL 5.0

Tags: laravel, controller, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

i want to call my controller inside the view please see attach images
[my view file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nS1es.png)

[my controller file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOvTN.png)

Comment: Post your code instead of image

Comment: Will you please elaborate? The question is not with enough description.

Comment: i want  to call my controller to my index.blade.php

this is my code

$Protections = new app\Http\Controllers\Protection;
echo Protections::test();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i think this will help you.

Call route:

```
Route::get('/', 'YourController@test');
```

Your Controller:

```
public function test() 
{
    return view('index');
}
```

index.blade.php

```
{{You are in index.blade.php}}
//Add your stuff
```

Comment: @Sheweta

how to call the " function test()  " ?

to index.blade.php i mean inside index.blade.php

Comment: do yoou want to pass parameters to your test method?